# IOS UIWebView encoding

Tags: ios, encoding, uiwebview

I am creating a browser with `UIWebView`. When I browse some non-English web site that is missing a `meta` tag, which means that `UIWebView` will use default encoding, then I can not see the web site show correctly...

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you could consider using the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method on your `UIWebView` to add some javascript dynamically. The javascript could append an appropriate `<meta>` element to the `<head>` of the document.